# How do I get recently added Swiftlint Rules

Tags: swiftlint

I have the latest version of Swiftlint (via brew).  When I check github, I see that they have added a bunch of rules since the release, even a few a couple of days ago. How do I get those rules onto my mac? Do I have to uninstall the version I have and reinstall the same version? (will that even get the new rules?) Do I have to download the zip from github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `brew update`. But some of the new code is not yet in the release branch. For the dev-branch you would need to pull the newest version manually. It is a shame that the new documentation on rules is so poor, because i ran into the exact same problem.

I would suggest waiting until the rules are in release branch and are deployed by brew. Sometimes those rules can be buggy and are not reliable.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `brew update` is to integrate SwiftLint using CocoaPods, and in that case you would update it with `pod update`.

I recommend the CocoaPods approach as it garanties that all co-developers get the same errors (and warnings), and avoids situations were one developer doesn't get any error, pushes code and confronts another developer to build errors.